# No desktop on new installation

Tags: desktop-environments

I have just installed Ubuntu on a laptop running XP pro and there are no desktop icons....in fact, there is no desktop at all. Can anyone help? I am a newb where linux is concerned and I have searched the net but find all the solutions too technical. I tried installing the cinnamon desktop but I cannot get anything to work in a terminal as it keeps asking for a password.

Comment: Did you set a password up when you installed?  There aren't supposed to be desktop *icons* but you should see [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution for your problem is related to the openGL Framebuffer Object. Disable it, this way:

Install manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run:

```
ccsm
```

Select the OpenGL section and then untick the Framebuffer Object option. If this fixes the issue it should be immediately visible. No reboot is required.

Clue from user: Flimm

You have set the password during the installation. You must remember that or you will need to reinstall.